# Why Tensorflow's MirroredStrategy and OneDevicestrategy does not work on colab?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, distributed-computing

I am trying to understand Tensorflow Distributed training using MirroredStrategy and it’s other variants. I already have a simple script with MNIST on colab but that needs to be tested on multiple GPUs. Running and implementing the code gives me an error as "ValueError: Distribute argument in compile is not available in TF 2.0 please create the model under the distribution strategy scope." I tried OneDeviceStrategy as well, but it is also not working. I want to compare time complexity and accuracy using various Distributed training methods. Here are a
[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKZRR.png) and a [Link to the code on Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1kMUrIZjNpL-Q7TG5CAfT6z-dyrpG78RZ).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is essentially the way you use the distribution strategy scope. In TF 2.0, you do not pass the distribution strategy to the compile method. Instead, you need to build your model and compile it inside of the distribution strategy scope. Note that the call to model.fit(...) should not be inside the distribution strategy scope. For example, this is a redacted version of your colab code which should solve your problem:

```
...

strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()

with strategy.scope():
  input_img = layers.Input(shape=IMG_SIZE)
  model = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same')(input_img)
  ... # model definition
  output_img = layers.Activation('softmax')(model)

  model = models.Model(input_img, output_img)

  model.compile(optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=["accuracy"])

...

history = model.fit(...)
```

Please see the [Using tf.distribute.Strategy with Keras](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training#using_tfdistributestrategy_with_keras) section of the [Distributed training with TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training) guide for more information.